# Link SharePoint List to Access 2010 - USer Information Lookup

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010

I have a lookup list that is used in a custom solution to provide information about a specific location. This list includes columns of type People and Groups.

Given the quantity of locations that will be available I'd be very keen that the list is maintained and imported from an Access database. I do something similar with my configurations list which works great. It just means I can rapidly deploy all configurations across different environments.

The problem I have encountered is that it doesn't seem to handle columns of data type People and Groups. The lookup is not available in Access. From what little i have found online, I'd not even sure if this is possible. This [article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-from-or-link-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA001230313.aspx) suggests that Access automatically creates a link to the USerInfo table. Even with this link, I cannot look up values.

Can someone please let me know if this is possible or a limitation and cannot be achieved when linking a list to Access?

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely possible, and MS Access should automatically link any dependent lists when you import a parent list that has lookups.

Check to make sure you don't have multiple UserInfo lists linked, like UserInfo1, UserInfo2, etc.  If so, delete all your linked SP lists and relink.